# How do I tell sp_send_dbmail to send an email only when there are results

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to tell sp_send_dbmail to only send an email when there are more than zero results?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't see any obvious way by looking at [the parameters in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx). Completely untested suggestion but maybe you could append a second query `;SELECT CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN 1/0 END` and set `@append_query_error` to 0?

Comment: which database are you working with? If you're using t-sql (Microsoft Server) you could use an IF-Statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to store the results of the query into a temp table. If rows exist, execute `sp_send_dbmail`, using a select from the temp table as the query. The proc *should* be able to see the temp table, but if not you may need to use a global temp table.